# Hide block which does not fit container height

Tags: html, css

I have example here http://jsfiddle.net/brain2xml/cVAMN/

```
<div id="container">
<div class="sep">1</div>
<div class="sep">2</div>
<div class="sep">3</div>
<div class="sep">4</div>
<div class="sep">5</div>
</div>
```

and css

```
.sep{
    border:1px solid red;
    height: 50px;
    width: 280px;
    margin: 10px;
}
#container{
    height: 170px;
    width: 300px;
    border:1px solid green;
}
```

I want blocks (block 3, 4 and 5) inside container been hide if they not whole inside container. If I put overflow property to container, the half of block #3 still visible. But I want show blocks if they whole visible in container.

Is it possible to do without js?

Comment: The "witch" in the title makes me chuckle a bit.

Comment: i dont think its possible by css you need to use JavaScript for that

Comment: @gersande - Wookey Hole - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wookey_Hole_Caves

Comment: you're using fixed sizes for the blocks and the container, can't you make it so that the container doesn't cut a block in half?

Comment: the container block height will be depend of content, so, if height various I want to hide some blocks for short content or show more if long

Comment: Check out the solution here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19757421/hide-blocks-that-does-not-fit-a-fixed-size-container

(Uses JavaScript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Using CSS you can achieve.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Gfuqq)

```
.sep{
    border:1px solid red;
    height: 50px;
    width: 280px;
    margin: 10px;
}
#container{
    min-height: 170px;
    width: 300px;
    border:1px solid green;
    padding:10px;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: '\0020';
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}
.clearfix {
  zoom: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use Script you can only change the height of the span divs to `height: 73px;` and set `overflow : hidden` for #container