# Hide blocks that does not fit a fixed size container

Tags: html, css

I have a container of a fixed size, containing a vertical list of blocks of varying heights .
I would like to hide all blocks that does not fit completely within the container.

So assuming something like this:

```css
#container{
    height: 150px;
    width: 220px;
    border:1px solid green;
    padding:10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.inner{
    border:1px solid blue;
    height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" >
    <div class="inner">A</div>
    <div class="inner">B</div>
    <div class="inner">C</div>
    <div class="inner">D</div>
</div>
```

(See: http://jsfiddle.net/TSCzS/)

I get something like this:

```
+-------------+
|             |
|  +-------+  |
|  | A     |  |
|  +-------+  |
|             |
|  +-------+  |
|  | B     |  |
|  +-------+  |
|             |
|  +-------+  |
+--| C     |--+
   +-------+  

   +-------+  
   | D     |  
   +-------+
```

I do not want to just have the C block clipped:
(as when simply using overflow:hidden on the container)

```
+-------------+
|             |
|  +-------+  |
|  | A     |  |
|  +-------+  |
|             |
|  +-------+  |
|  | B     |  |
|  +-------+  |
|             |
|  +-------+  |
|  | C     |  |
+-------------+
```

but instead, the blocks C and D should be hidden like this:

```
+-------------+
|             |
|  +-------+  |
|  | A     |  |
|  +-------+  |
|             |
|  +-------+  |
|  | B     |  |
|  +-------+  |
|             |
|             |
+-------------+
```

How can I do this?

My application for this is that I have a full screen browser window (in a digital signage application) showing the "latest news". The units have no input devices, so scrolling is not possible.

A similar question, but without a working solution:
[Hide block which does not fit container height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18941262/hide-block-which-does-not-fit-container-height)

Thanks.

Comment: JavaScript an option?

Comment: Yes, JavaScript is OK if not to heavyweight. I'm planning on using a Raspberry Pi for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can imagine a solution is via JavaScript. CSS itself wont help.

Here's an update of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bukfixart/TSCzS/1/

This snippet selects all clipping elements and hides them.

```
$('.inner', '#container').filter(function() {
    return $('#container').offset().top + $('#container').height() < $(this).offset().top + $(this).height();
}).hide();
```

For this solution you need to use jQuery

---

edit:

**For all the pure CSS enthusiasts ;-)**

http://jsfiddle.net/bukfixart/CfMer/

I tried a solution without javascript and used css3 transformations instead. Therefore some markup changes are necessary

```
<div id="outercontainer" >
    <div id="container" >
        <div class="outer">
            <div class="inner">A</div>
        </div>
        <div class="outer">
            <div class="inner">B</div>
        </div>
        <div class="outer">
            <div class="inner">C</div>
        </div>
        <div class="outer">
            <div class="inner">D</div>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:left;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's the a little bit stranger style code

```
#outercontainer {
    width:240px;  /* container width + padding */
    height:170px; /* container height + padding */
    border:1px solid green;
}    

#container{
    height: 220px;  /* container width ^^ */
    width: 150px;   /* container height ^^ */
    padding:10px;
    overflow: hidden;

    position:relative;
    left:35px;    /* half of difference from width + padding to outer container width */
    top:-35px;      /* half of difference from height + padding to outer container height */

    -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
}

.outer{
    float:left;

    height:202px;  /* width of the inner box + border */
    width:52px;    /* height of the inner box + border */
    margin:10px 10px 10px 0px;
    line-height:200px; /* width of the inner box */

    vertical-align:middle;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg);
}

.inner{
    border:1px solid blue;
    height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 50px;

    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;
    left: -75px;   /* half of difference between width and height */
}
```

Comment: Cool, not very heavyweight :)

Sorry about not being able to upvote (I'm to low on reputation)